# azure .net core app with IS4: web api call fails with "Bearer error=invalid_token The issuer is invalid"

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4, nswag

I have a **.net Core 3.1** app running in an azure web app for containers(linux) service.  This app is a web api project with an **angular 9** front end.  It uses **Identity server 4** for authorization.

For reference I am using this [clean architecture framework template](https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/pull/171) for my project (the add docker support pr).

The app runs in the service just fine.  The front end works and I can "log in" using ID4 and I can see that the authorization token are returned when I log in.

### THE PROBLEM:

When I make a call to the backend web api from the front end angular client app I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://*********.azurewebsites.net' is invalid"
```

I am tempted to add a manual setting for the ***IssuerUri*** but the [identity server 4 docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html) recommend against doing this so I did not.  Maybe having this run in docker makes it different.

I did have to add support for forwarding headers to get IS4 to work properly in *startup.cs configureServices* according to [these docs for proxy load balancers.](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies-1)  I had to add ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED=true to my application settings

When I compare fiddler results for the requests, I can see that the **AspNetCore.Antiforgery** is the same for login and web api calls but the **.AspNetCore.Identity.Application** value is different.

I am using **nSwag** to auto generate api service calls for angular if that makes a difference.

### QUESTION:

can someone help me figure out why I can login but all web api requests fail with the unauthorized error above?

thanks in advance.
JK

### EDIT 1

I used fiddler to get the authorization token for the request and used jwt.io to parse it.  The iss value was the same as the app/web api:

```
"iss": "https://******.azurewebsites.net",
```

IS4 used this domain to log in and that worked properly.  If that value is correct, is there another thing that might be wrong?

### EDIT 2:

Just for more context.

My app uses in statup.cs **Configure**:

```
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

As a result I needed to add the following code to make sure the headers get forwarded in the requests between app service's handling of the TSL, load balancer/proxy and my docker container (starup.cs ConfigureServices):

```
// the following is documented here:
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#forward-the-scheme-for-linux-and-non-iis-reverse-proxies-1
// it is needed to run kestrel in azure app service in http with header forwarding
if (string.Equals(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_FORWARDEDHEADERS_ENABLED"),
    "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                                   ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
        // Only loopback proxies are allowed by default.
        // Clear that restriction because forwarders are enabled by explicit 
        // configuration.
        options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        options.KnownProxies.Clear();
    });
}
```

I get the following error in the logs which confirm the same error above as an Issuer mismatch

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException:
> IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden. For more
> details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Did not match:
> validationParameters.ValidIssuer ...

I am using the following default setup for the Jwt token:

```
 services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

If i navigate to the **https://*******.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks** I get the following JSON setting for my OIDC setup:

```
{
  "issuer": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net",
  "jwks_uri": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks",
  "authorization_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/authorize",
  "token_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/token",
  "userinfo_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/userinfo",
  "end_session_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/endsession",
  "check_session_iframe": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/checksession",
  "revocation_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/revocation",
  "introspection_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/introspect",
  "device_authorization_endpoint": "https://*******.azurewebsites.net/connect/deviceauthorization",
  "frontchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "frontchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "backchannel_logout_supported": true,
  "backchannel_logout_session_supported": true,
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "CleanArchitecture.WebUIAPI",
    "offline_access"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "sub",
    "name",
    ....
    "updated_at"
  ],
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "authorization_code",
    "client_credentials",
    "refresh_token",
    "implicit",
    "password",
    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
  ],
  "response_types_supported": [
    "code",
    "token",
    "id_token",
    "id_token token",
    "code id_token",
    "code token",
    "code id_token token"
  ],
  "response_modes_supported": ["form_post", "query", "fragment"],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": ["RS256"],
  "subject_types_supported": ["public"],
  "code_challenge_methods_supported": ["plain", "S256"],
  "request_parameter_supported": true
}
```

I compared the Issuer in this document and they are the same as the one in the token as shown decoded above.

I am still not sure how to debug this to figure out where the issuer mismatch is happening.

**NOTE:** I have narrowed this down a bit.  All calls to the built in/default IS4 endpoints work.  Its only the custom webAPI endpoints I define in my controllers that are not validating the token properly.

***Any webAPI endpoint with [Authorize] attribute fails with invalid issuer***

### EDIT 3:

Thanks to @d_f comment I used the IS4 docs for [adding local API](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html)
I added the following call to my services initialization in startu.ca configure services:

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
services.AddLocalApiAuthentication();  // I added this line after the above line
```

I then changed the **[Authorize]** attribute at the top of my webAPI controller to:

```
//[Authorize]
[Authorize(IdentityServerConstants.LocalApi.PolicyName)]
```

However, I am still getting the same error.  Only on my custom webAPI endpoints, the IS4 endpoints all work.  Login works but not any web api endpoints that have [Authorize] attribute.

### EDIT 4:

I removed the above settings and chnaged my services.AddAUthentication() to the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
    .AddLocalApi(options =>
        options.ExpectedScope = "IdentityServer4");
```

I also tried:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
    .AddLocalApi();
```

I used the policy name "IdentityServer4" because it appears to be a default policy within IS4

Here is what the full context looks like:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt() 
    .AddLocalApi(options =>
        options.ExpectedScope = "IdentityServer4");
```

This works locally on my machine with all these variations.  Its just when run inside container in azure web app that I get the issuer failure for my custom webAPI endpoints.

### SOLUTION:

I found a solution thanks to all the help here.  IS4 out of the box attempts to set the **ISS / Issuer** automatically.  This works locally but in my production environment my container run in azure web apps for containers.  Azure places my container inside of another container for load balancing/proxy to handle the https encryption as well.  As a result there is a difference between the auto detected IS4 issuer in my container and the azure web app URL.

By manually setting the issuer in my code the error went away and everything works.

You can do this in two places

1. in your appsettings.jsson like:

```
     "IdentityServer": {
        "IssuerUri": "https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net",
```

2. or in code like this:

```
      services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.IssuerUri = "https://your.azurewebsites.net/";
                })
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Hope this helps someone else and thanks again to all who helped here

Comment: What is the issuer in the access token? Does it match the expected issuer in the API?

Comment: How do I figure that out?

Comment: Pass the requests to the identity server or to the API through some proxy like Fiddler.

Comment: thanks @ToreNestenius and d_f , I edited my answer to show that the iss value of the token is the expected value, but I am still unsure why I get the error

Comment: @d_f I have edited my question to show more details.  I use the default configuration from services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt(); and do not explicitly set the Authority setting anywhere.

Comment: i missed the point you use "all in one" template, assumed your identityserver hosted separately. for all-in-one you can try to switch to 
`services.AddAuthentication().AddLocalApi("token", isAuth => {/*customize validation here*/});`

Comment: @d_f I added edit #3 to describe what I tried thanks to your comment.  I am having trouble setting up the AddLocalApi function.  I just tried the default AddLocalApiAuthentication() that IS4 provides

Comment: @d_f thanks for your continued help.  I am having trouble finding examples for AddLocalApi()  I added Edit #4 to show two ways I tried to use it.

Comment: I assumed .AddLocalApi("customSchemeName", options => options.ExpectedScope = "IdentityServer4"); together with [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "customSchemeName")] to employ the proper handler. and you don't need .AddIdentityServerJwt() in this case. I guess in all your attempts the default handler was invoked, so you always getting the same result. you have to point to your new scheme in the attribute

Comment: hi, have you solved this? any further assistance needed?

Comment: @d_f unfortunately not.  I tried your suggestion and it still does not work.  I am new to IS4 and I feel like my knowledge gap is making it hard for me to truly narrow down the issue.  My implementation is in side an open source .net core starter project.  as a result there are other factors involved.  This problem only appears inside docker containers running in azure web app.  locally when the app is run in side and outside a container it works.  I'm worried some other environment configuration in azure app service is effecting this but I'm not sure.  I am reading IS4 docs currently

Comment: to increase my understanding to help with debugging the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION:

I found a solution thanks to all the help here.  IS4 out of the box attempts to set the **ISS / Issuer** automatically.  This works locally but in my production environment my container run in azure web apps for containers.  Azure places my container inside of another container for load balancing/proxy to handle the https encryption as well.  As a result there is a difference between the auto detected IS4 issuer in my container and the azure web app URL.

By manually setting the issuer in my code the error went away and everything works.

You can do this in two places

1. in your appsettings.jsson like:

```
     "IdentityServer": {
        "IssuerUri": "https://yourapp.azurewebsites.net",
```

2. or in code like this:

```
      services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.IssuerUri = "https://your.azurewebsites.net/";
                })
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Hope this helps someone else and thanks again to all who helped here

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture your token and use https://jwt.ms to parse it.

According to your error message: `invalid token The issuer is invalid`, so you should check the `iss` Claims in the token to make sure it is as expected in the API The issuer matches. see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims).

[image]

Comment: hello,  I have checked the authorization token and it shows "iss": "https://********.azurewebsites.net", which is my app running in azure.  The IS4 server is running on that domain as well.  I have had some problems with ssl setup, is it possible that if the request is http instead of https it would throw this error?  thanks

Comment: the protocol must match , you cant mix HTTP and HTTPS

Comment: @JKing  Hi,I have not tested using http, but, as Tore Nestenius said, you cannot mix HTTP and HTTPS.