# ASP.NET Core with React and IdentityServer 4 on Azure: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've created a .NET 6 app using `ASP.NET Core with React.js` Visual Studio 2022 template.
Then I added TypeScript to the client app part. I'm also using IdentityServer 4.

Here's how I register the IdentityServer in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddIdentityResources()
                .AddApiResources()
                .AddClients()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

Here's my `IdentityServer` part of the `appsettings.json`:

```json
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyApp.App": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  }
```

I have this sample `WeatherForecastController` that was included in the template with `[Authorize]` attribute on it.

Everything works fine locally, however as soon as I deploy to Azure (via BitBucket on-commit deployment), I can register/login to the app without problems, but while trying to access the authorized route I get a `401 Unauthorized` error with this message:

```
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The issuer 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net' is invalid"
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809717/azure-net-core-app-with-is4-web-api-call-fails-with-bearer-error-invalid-toke) I added my app's Azure URL to the `appsettings.json`:

```json
"IdentityServer": {
    "IssuerUri": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net",
    "Clients": {
      "MyApp.App": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  }
```

But it didn't help.

What has helped, however, is defining this URI in the code:

```csharp
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
                {
                    options.IssuerUri = "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net";
                })
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddIdentityResources()
                .AddApiResources()
                .AddClients()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

However, it seems like a code smell. As [IdentityServer docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/options.html) says:

> It is recommended to not set this property, which infers the issuer name from the host name that is used by the clients.

Also, it's a bit weird as I need to change this URI in C# locally when developing on localhost to make everything work correctly. Of course, I can extract it to `appconfig.json`, but it still seems odd to me that it's needed.

I don't really understand this problem, so I've been looking more.

I found other questions that suggested pasting my token (obtained when the authorization failed) into https://jwt.ms/ and here's the output:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "7BEDB584D24C2C0D6619ED5C802A4EEF",
  "typ": "at+jwt"
}.{
  "nbf": 1638590243,
  "exp": 1638593843,
  "iss": "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net",
  "aud": "MyApp.AppAPI",
  "client_id": "MyApp.App",
  "sub": "d611ae4d12614a94aeac0399fac81b3b",
  "auth_time": 1638590237,
  "idp": "local",
  "jti": "648F96B7DA864DB28FB06540325310A6",
  "sid": "6187CB0CF53F3049062BD8B7728F6C68",
  "iat": 1638590243,
  "scope": [
    "MyApp.AppAPI",
    "openid",
    "profile"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}.[Signature]
```

The only thing that surprises me here is this `MyApp.AppAPI` - I have no idea what's this `AppAPI` part. I have nothing like that in my ASP.NET Core solution or client app. Is this something specific to Azure? Maybe that's the problem here?

Any help in plain English would be appreciated - I'm quite new to Azure

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100 percent sure in case of Identity Server, but generally, you also need to add authentication in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
{
    opt.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net",
        ValidAudience = "https://myapp.azurewebsites.net"
     };
 });
```

And the values in ValidIssuer obviously needs to match the issuer used in JWT

Comment: I'm adding authentication for IdentityServer, but it's simpler: 
services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
As I wrote in my original post, adding IssuerUri in code for IdentityServer does the job, but I wonder if that's the properway/needed